# I am having an error while trying to make a get request on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, get

```
String url = 'http://localhost:9000/user/john.doe@email.com';
Future<String> get makeRequest() async {
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application"});

         print(response.body);

}
```

I get an error on makeRequests() that says "This function has a return type of 'Future', but doesn't end with a return statement."

Comment: `return response.body;`

Comment: change var response to http.Response response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return **data** corresponding to the **return type** of the function.

```
String url = 'http://localhost:9000/user/john.doe@email.com';

Future<String> get makeRequest() async 
{
    var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    print(response.body);

    return(response.body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return a String in the function with the header Future< String >. You probably want to return response.body